# How to change Go Ethereum ECC Curve

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging, secp256k1

In `Geth\crypto` I found the default implementation of ECC curve (secp256k1). I would like to change it to secp256r1 curve for my private network. In normal circumstances, all I need to change is the curve parameters, which I found it in `Geth\crypto\secp256k1\curve.go`. I also found native implementation at `Geth\crypto\secp256k1\libsecp256k1` so I am not confident by changing curve parameters in `curve.go` is suffice. Could someone please point me to the right direction

Comment: you can use `guru` package to find the `callers` of the encryption function and find out if its called or not within the code.I am using this tool: https://github.com/fzipp/pythia